# Gradle - Could not target platform: 'Java SE 8' using tool chain: 'JDK 7 (1.7)'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to import Gradle project in Intellij Idea with local Gradle distrib and getting stacktrace with the following message: `Could not target platform: 'Java SE 8' using tool chain: 'JDK 7 (1.7)'`.
Could anyone explain please what could be the reason?

Comment: which JDK version you using ? try to use the same as defined in graddle

Comment: I've put the path to the same JDK both to Gradle (via gradle.properties) and in Idea project structure. Is that what you meant? Did I miss anything?

Comment: yup , did it work after that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: can you add the screen shot showing the intelliJ level SDK?

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. Please, see the answer below. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: I get this issue when i run it in jenkins CICD pipeline. When ran in intelij, it works perfectly fine. We were running the project with java version 1.8, changed it to 1.11 in the sourceCompatibility in the build.gradle file. Any solution for CICD pipeline since below answers seems on the intelij side

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finally I imported my Gradle project. These are the steps:

1. I switched from local Gradle distrib to Intellij Idea Gradle Wrapper
   (gradle-2.14).
2. I pointed system variable `JAVA_HOME` to **JDK 8** (it was 7th previously) as I had
   figured out by experiments that Gradle Wrapper could process the
   project with **JDK 8** only.
3. I deleted previously manually created file *gradle.properties* (with
   `org.gradle.java.home`variable) in windows user .gradle directory
   as, I guessed, it didn't bring any additional value to Gradle.

Comment: In Eclipse I had this problem as well, because my system had the JAVA_HOME env variable set to a JDK7 (run `echo $JAVA_HOME` to check). Change the JAVA_HOME system-wide or start eclipse with `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk8 eclipse` to mitigate this problem

Answer (score 437):

This is what worked for me (Intellij Idea 2018.1.2):

1) Navigate to: File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

2) Gradle JVM: change to version 1.8

3) Re-run the gradle task

Comment: There is no such option in IntelliJ 2018.1.6 (community edition)

Comment: On Mac, Navigate to "IntelliJ Idea" -> "Preferences" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Build Tools" -> "Gradle"

Comment: i ran into this problem again...after I already upvoted it once who knows how long ago... ++

Comment: For those who spend an hour like me to find it in a newer versions of intellij, press CTRL_SHIFT_A and write "settings" to open settings. Then type 'gradle' in the search, and u will see below the "Build, Execution, Deployment" and the "Build Tools"...

Answer (score 77):

For IntelliJ 2019:

Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM

Select correct version.

Answer (score 41):

For IntelliJ 2019, JDK 13 and gRPC:

Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM

and **Select correct version**.

you might also have to adding below line in your build.gradle **dependencies**

```
compileOnly group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
```

Answer (score 11):

Since I had to compile some source with 7 compatibility, because of some legacy system and ran into the same problem. I found out that in the gradle configuration there where two options set to java 8

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

switching these to 1.7 solved the problem for me, keeping JAVA_HOME pointing to the installed JDK-7

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a very related issue but for higher Java versions:

```
$ ./gradlew clean assemble

... <other normal Gradle output>

Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
```

I noticed that the task succeeded when running using InteliJ. Adding a file (same level as build.gradle) called `.java-version` solved my issue:

```
 # .java-version
 11.0.3
```

Answer (score 5):

you have to change  the  -> sourceCompatibility = '1.7'   in  build.Gradle

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to the top right corner of IntelliJ -> click the icon
2. In the Project Structure window -> Select project -> In the Project SDK, choose the correct version -> Click Apply -> Click Okay

Answer (score 2):

Adding to all information above to change the JVM version on IntelliJ settings, I'd like to mention that you have to do that for all modules of your project.

So if you are working on a multimodule project, make sure you changed the JVM version for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

And so I see from other answers that there are several ways of dealing with it. But I don't believe this. It has to be reduced into one way. I love IDE but, but if I follow the IDE steps provided from different answers I know this is not the fundamental algebra. My error looked like:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
```

And the way to solve it scientifically is:

```
vi build.gradle
```

To change from:

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('11')
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('11')
}
```

to become:

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('8')
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('8')
}
```

The scientific method is that method that is open for argumentation and deals on common denominators.

Comment: This is helpful. But then other files starts to give error. May be the best way is to upgrade the jdk to 11

Answer (score 1):

Although this question specifically asks about IntelliJ, this was the first result I received on Google, so I believe that many Eclipse users may have the same problem using Buildship.

You can set your Gradle JVM in Eclipse by going to Gradle Tasks (in the default view, down at the bottom near the console), right-clicking on the specific task you are trying to run, clicking "Open Gradle Run Configuration..." and moving to the Java Home tab and picking the correct JVM for your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running gradle build from IntelliJ terminal do followings:

1. Check what java version JAVA_HOME is pointing to with command:
   INBENJKUMARLM1:payment-service jkuma00$ **echo $JAVA_HOME**
   /Users/jkuma00/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.11.9.1-amzn
2. Check source compatibility version in **build.gradle** file.
   **sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11**

ROOT CAUSE: Major java version reported by $JAVA_HOME must match with java version value which sourceCompatibility property has. If there is a mismatch. This issue will happen.

RESOLUTION: Either change source compatiblity version or change JAVA_HOME value. Motive is to match these versions and everything should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Java 9 JDK 9.0.4

1. Go to the top left corner of Android Studio (4.1.1)-> click on File
2. Click on Setting
3. Click on Build, Execution, Deployment
4. Click on  Compiler
5. Click on Kotlin  Compiler
6. Target JVM version

**File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Kotlin Compiler**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple versions of JDKs, a couple of things to note.

1. All the JDKs need to be added to the path.
2. Since, the JAVA_HOME variable needs to point to one path, assign it to your most frequently used jdk (ex: Java 8). And for rest of the JDK versions, create and assign separate java-home environment variables. e.g. JAVA_HOME_11 for Java 11 and so forth.
3. For build tools such as gradle, if you're building using CLI, or pipelines, you will need to point your JDK_HOME to the specific version needed. e.g. JAVA_HOME_11 if your project is based on Java 11.
4. Tools like intellij idea also allow you to set up project wise JDK version. This in-turn helps them choose the *corresponding runtime*.

In my experience, all four checks need to be made if your project is complaining of Java inconsistency during compilation, build or runs.