# Integration test cases not working after jdk10 upgrade

Tags: java, java-8, automated-tests, cucumber, integration-testing

Getting the below error while running functional test cases after upgrading to jdk10.

Could not target platform: 'Java SE 10' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.

build.gradle

```
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.Dockerfile
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os


buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release'
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/release'
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot'
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
        }

        maven{
            url='https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath ("com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.2.1")
        classpath ("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5")
        classpath "gradle.plugin.au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-gradle_2.12:3.6.0-rc.0"
        classpath ("com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0")

    }
}

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "au.com.dius.pact" version "3.6.0-rc.0"
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "1.4.17"
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "3.4.2"

}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'au.com.dius.pact'
apply plugin: 'scala'


group = 'com'
sourceCompatibility = 10

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RELEASE'
}

//start of integration tests changes
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('test/functional-api/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('test/functional-api/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
//end of integration tests changes
dependencies {
    //web (Tomcat, Logging, Rest)
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',   name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    // Redis
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    //Mongo Starter
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name:'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'

    // Configuration processor - To Generate MetaData Files. The files are designed to let  developers offer â€œcode completionâ€? as users are working with application.properties
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    // Actuator - Monitoring
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'

    //Sleuth - Tracing
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    //Hystrix - Circuit Breaker
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix'
    // Hystrix - Dashboard
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard'
    // Thymeleaf
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    //Voltage
    // Device Detection

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'  
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.2-jre'
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0')
    compile('org.json:json:20170516')

    //Swagger
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.8.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version:'2.8.0'

    //jkd10 fixes
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind',name: 'jaxb-api', version:'2.3.0'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.soap', name: 'javax.xml.soap-api', version:'1.3.5'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj', name: 'saaj-impl', version:'1.4.0'
    compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version:'2.3.0.1'

    //Lombok
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok',version:'1.18.2'
    //compile group: 'io.smartcat', name: 'cassandra-diagnostics-connector21', version: '1.4.10'
    //Testing
    //Spring  WS Test
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version:'2.4.0.RELEASE'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json"
    }
    //Pact
    testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name: 'pact-jvm-provider-gradle_2.12', version: '3.5.7'
    testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name:'pact-jvm-provider-junit_2.12',version:'3.5.13'
    testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name:'pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.12', version:'3.5.13'

    //Embedded mongo for testing
    testCompile group: 'de.flapdoodle.embed', name:'de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo',version:'2.0.1'
    //testCompile group: 'cz.jirutka.spring', name: 'embedmongo-spring', version: '1.1'

    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-jvm', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '3.0.2'
    compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '3.0.2'

    testCompile('org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit-spring:3.5.0.1'){
        exclude group: 'org.cassandraunit', module: 'cassandra-unit'
    }
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cassandraunit/cassandra-unit-shaded
    compile group: 'org.cassandraunit', name: 'cassandra-unit-shaded', version: '3.5.0.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hectorclient/hector-core
    compile group: 'org.hectorclient', name: 'hector-core', version: '2.0-0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-all', version: '3.11.3'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version:'2.4.0.RELEASE' //changes for integration tests
    integrationTestCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"){ //changes for integration tests
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json"
    }
    //integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5' //changes for integration tests
    //integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5' //changes for integration tests

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }

}

test {
    //ignoreFailures = true
    reports.junitXml.enabled = false
    reports.html.enabled = true
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        maxHeapSize = '2048m'
        minHeapSize = '1024m'
        //classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}
jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/coverage"
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: [
                                '**/config*',
                                '**/coupons/TextToClipApplication*',
                                '**/bean/*Request*',
                                '**/bean/*Response*',
                    ])
        })
    }
}
test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.2"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

//start of changes for integration tests
task apifunctionaltest(type: Test) {
    systemProperty "integrationurl", System.getProperty("integrationurl")
    reports.junitXml.enabled = false
    reports.html.enabled = true
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}
//end of changes for integration tests
```

We are using cucumber to test it. Same code is working in local using gradle, but not working in server. Anyone faced the same problem ?

Comment: You need to add details. What tool is giving you this error? What tools are you using to run your test cases?

Comment: From what I can see, it is the version issue. (Your framework and Java 10 compatibility issue).
You need to upgrade the wrapper of your framework: upgrade version of your framework

Comment: 20 fps: no point in laughing at the OP. Downvote, close vote, give a helpful comment. Anything else is no longer *welcome* here.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggestions. Added more details to the question.

Comment: We do already have [Could not target platform: 'Java SE 9' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47500674/2711488) and [Could not target platform: 'Java SE 8' using tool chain: 'JDK 7 (1.7)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43995886/2711488) and the answer each time is “`JAVA_HOME`”. Did you check `JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Issue for us is build server has been using jdk8. Now it is resolved after changing the build template to jdk10.