# Compile android app with java 11 dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-11

I am trying to build an android app with some dependencies compiled in java 11.

I have configured this in the build.gradle :

```
android {
  compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility = 1.11
      targetCompatibility = 1.11
  }
    ...
}
```

And I have configured my project structure with the java 11 sdk.

I am using this version of the android tool build plugin :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

And this version of gradle :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

I am also pointing to java 11 for the Gradle JVM.

But when I compile the app, I always get this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
```

I do not understand why.

I have checked my JAVA_HOME and my java -version and they both point to 11.

Does anybody has an idea of what is going on ?

Thanks

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114212/2683297

Comment: Not working as well... Now I get this error : ```class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.```

Comment: Do you compile inside Android Studio or on a stand-alone command-line? Android Studio contains an integrated Java 8 JDK which is used by default.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and the stand-alone Gradle inside the project. IntelliJ is delegating the build to Gradle. And I have changed the Gradle JVM to use java 11.

Answer (score 6):

Try like this :

```
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Gives android.annotations not found

Answer (score -3):

If using Kotlin in your module, your `build.gradle` file should be set as so:

```
android {
 ...
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
  }

  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Gives android.annotations not found