# Cannot set Gradle JVM version in my Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Everyone in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995886/gradle-could-not-target-platform-java-se-8-using-tool-chain-jdk-7-1-7) suggest to set the Gradle JVM to version 1.8, but I just cannot find that version in Intellij.

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle leads me to:

[image]

Project structure doesn't help either:

[image]

There is no place in Intellij where I can set the Gradle JVM version.

Gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

I know AS requires JDK 8, but I saw some people pull off using 11 in the compileOptions by setting Gradle JVM to 8, but I can't do that on my Intellij for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up JDK for your project in `File|Project Structure|SDK Location|JDK Location`.